# Как задать каждому элементу listbox один обработчик?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Вот я создаю элементы:

```
ListBox1->Items->Add(ned1->Text);
```

Задаю им обработчики

```
for(int i(0);i<ListBox1->Count;i++)
    {
        ListBox1->ItemByIndex(i)->OnClick = ListBoxItem1Click;
    }
```

И также создал обработчик.

```
void __fastcall TTabbedForm::TabItemClick(TObject *Sender)
{
ListBox2->Items->SaveToFile("/sdcard/"+(ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex])+".txt");
}
```

Программа работает так: при первом нажатии на любой из созданных элементов(TListBox) вылетает ошибка(фото)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные нажатия на этот же или любые другие элементы происходит то что в обработчике (т.е. работает должным образом). в чем проблема. 
Мне кажется в том что я  исользую индекс выбраного элемента в его же обработчике. если да то как сделать чтоб работало?

Comment: а что же должно прибежать в sender? строка?

Comment: если честно, не знаю что значат эти аргументы.

Comment: Sender - это указатель на объект, который вызвал данное событие. Так как по логике вещей, у Вас это собитие должна вызывать строка в списке, то она там и должна быть. Но проблема в том, что строки в списке - это просто строки, а не объекты. Но думаю, этот код Вам поможет `void __fastcall TForm1::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  Edit1->Text = ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, Вы создаете Multi-Device Application на базе Tabbed шаблона. В таком случае, функция вида `TTabbedForm::TabItemClick(TObject *Sender)` назначена на обработку события `OnClick` для конкретной вкладки:

> [image: tabbed]

Чтобы написать универсальный обработчик для всех вкладок, нужно:

1. Завязать для **всех** вкладок обработчик события `OnClick` на упомянутую функцию:

   > [image: OnClick]
2. В функции обрабатываться аргумент `Sender` как указатель на `TTabItem`. Например, так:

   ```
   TTabItem* item = static_cast<TTabItem*>(Sender);
   ```

   `item` в данном случае будет указывать на экземпляр той вкладки, на которую кликнули. Действия с ним будут затрагивать исключительно выбранную вкладку.

Упомянутый Вами `ListBox1` к сути дела не относится. А если Вам нужно обрабатывать клик на элементах `TListBox`, находящегося на форме, то обработчик `OnItemClick` имел бы совсем другую сигнатуру:

```
TTabbedForm::ListBox1ItemClick(TCustomListBox * const Sender, TListBoxItem * const Item)
```

Тут уже указатель на элемент списка передаётся явно.

Comment: Вот мне нужна именно обработка элементов TListBox.
Я сделал вот так.
   
     for(int i(0);i<ListBox1->Count;i++)
    {
 ListBox1->ItemByIndex(i)->OnClick = ListBoxItem1Click;
 }
И вот обработчик.
    void __fastcall TTabbedForm::ListBoxItem1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
    istBox2->Items->SaveToFile("/sdcard/"+(ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex])+".txt");
    }
Но как я понимаю в аргументы нужно что то другое писать

Comment: @Макс добавьте актуальную информацию в вопрос путём его редактирования. Комментарии для этого не предназначены.

Comment: хорошо, сейчас сделаю